# how to display images from local folder to view using mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using MVC. i need to upload the image and display it in same page.
i have uploaded the image and store the image in local folder.
how to display the images from local folder file using mvc

Comment: You can find your answer here: [Displaying Files on the Page](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/689_Uploading_and_Displaying_Files_Using_ASP_NET_MVC_Framework.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create an action that will load the file from the folder and return it.

Use `FileContentResult`:

```
public FileContentResult Display(string filename) {
   byte[] byteArray = GetImageFromDisk(filename);
   return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "image/jpeg");
}
```

*The above is a very simplistic sample to get you going.*